# Pass the form data in the URL after clicking on the drop down list values using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, url

My form is as follows:
I am using nodejs and javascript.And here depending on the value selected by the user from the dropdown list,accordingly that url is called.Like for the movie options:"localhost:3000/new" will be called.This works fine! but it is simply getting redirected to the url without any parameters of the form .I want the form values also to be passed along with the url .How can this be done?
Please help?
Thanks :)

```
   <form>
  <input type="text"  name="currentloc" class="textbox" id="currentloc"  
placeholder="Your location"/>
<input type="text" name="destloc" id="destloc"  autofocus="autofocus" 
class="textbox" placeholder="Enter the destination"/>     
First Event : <select name="events" onchange="location = this.value;">
  <option value="" >Select your first event</option><br><br>
  <option  value="/new" name="movies" id="movie" method="get">Watch a 
Movie</option>
  <option value="/food" name="restuarantis" id="rest" >Restaurant table 
 booking</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you could do in your form:

```
<body>
    <form name="pickerForm" method="GET" action="">
        <input type="text" name="currentloc" class="textbox" id="currentloc" placeholder="Your location" />

        <input type="text" name="destloc" id="destloc" autofocus="autofocus" class="textbox" placeholder="Enter the destination" />

        First Event :
        <select name="events" onchange="return loadCorrectPage(event);">
            <option value="" >Select your first event</option><br><br>
            <option value="/new" name="movies" id="movie" method="get">Watch a Movie</option>
            <option value="/food" name="restuarantis" id="rest" >Restaurant table booking</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <script>
        function loadCorrectPage(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log(event.target.value);
            document.forms['pickerForm'].action = event.target.value;
            document.forms['pickerForm'].submit();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

1. `document.forms['pickerForm']` matches the form element `<form name="pickerForm"` because of `name=`
2. You have to use `method="GET"` to send the data in the form to your node.js backend and make them available on `req.query`
3. We are using `action=""` because we will set it using JavaScript
4. When a change happens in your `select` element, we run the function `loadCorrectPage()` and we pass in `event` which is a variable that holds the data about the onchange event
5. Then, we need to create the function
6. `event.preventDefault()` is probably unnecessary here, but good to understand how it works if you don't
7. `event.target.value` holds the value of the changed option
8. We update `document.forms['pickerForm'].action` to the changed option, which means `action=""` is now either `action="/new"` or `action="/food"`
9. We call `document.forms['pickerForm'].submit()` which submits the form!

Now, in your node.js backend, you need corresponding routes. If you are using Express, they will look like this:

```
app.get('/new', function(req, res) {
    console.log('\nSomeone just picked movies!');
    console.log('Current location:', req.query.currentloc);
    console.log('Destination:', req.query.destloc);
});

app.get('/food', function(req, res) {
    console.log('\nSomeone just picked restaurants!');
    console.log('Current location:', req.query.currentloc);
    console.log('Destination:', req.query.destloc);
});
```